# How below python function output is valid according to global and local scope theory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I encountered a situation that confused me about *global* and *local* scopes.

```
x = 25
def display(a, b=x):
    print(a, b)
            
x = 15
```

Output:

```
>>> display(3)
3 25
```

How is the output is `3 25` and not `3 15`?

Comment: Function default arguments are calculated when the function is _defined_, not when it is _called_.  At the time the function was defined, x was 25.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133013/476) in the duplicate explains it best.